# MySQL Query - Join Three Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three MySQL tables that look like the following:

inventory table

```
  sn    |    hostname
-----------------------
  1234       host123
  2345       host456
  4567       host789
  6789       host910
```

reservation table

```
  orderid   |    serial    |   start_date    |    end_date    
----------------------------------------------------------
      1           1234         2015-09-10        2015-10-25
      2           2345         2015-10-21        2016-02-01
      2           4567         2015-10-21        2016-02-01
      3           6789         2015-08-01        2015-12-31
```

order detail table

```
  order_id    |    assigned_to   
---------------------------------
      1              Mark
      2              John
      3              Paul
```

I'm attempting to do a query from all 3 tables like this:

```
SELECT `serial`, `hostname`, `orderid`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `assigned_to` 
FROM `reservation`, `inventory`, `orders` 
WHERE `sn` IN(SELECT `serial` 
              FROM `reservation` 
              WHERE '2015-12-10' <= `end_date` AND '2015-12-10' >= `start_date`) 
      AND `serial` = `sn` AND `orderid` = `order_id`
```

In my query example, I just want to display results that fit within the date range I am choosing, but I end up getting all the results regardless of the date range I choose.  Example query result is this:

```
  serial   |   hostname  |   orderid   |   start_date   |   end_date   |   assigned_to 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1234        host123          1          2015-09-10      2015-10-25       Mark
   2345        host456          2          2015-10-21      2016-02-01       John
   4567        host789          2          2015-10-21      2016-02-01       John
   6789        hout910          3          2015-08-01      2015-12-31       Paul
```

But the result I desire, based on the above example query, is this:

```
  serial   |   hostname  |   orderid   |   start_date   |   end_date   |   assigned_to 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2345        host456          2          2015-10-21      2016-02-01       John
   4567        host789          2          2015-10-21      2016-02-01       John
   6789        hout910          3          2015-08-01      2015-12-31       Paul
```

What am I doing wrong with my query, and how can I achieve the desired result?  I've tried the same with `INNER JOINS` as well but end up with the same result.

Comment: None of your reservations both start and end on December 10th. What is that subquery supposed to be doing?

Comment: In this example I just want to see what is reserved "today", where today is December 10th.  In the above example, I shouldn't get the first reservation because it ended on 10-25-2015.

Comment: I get the correct results here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16078/1

Comment: I think you wanted and `or` not `and`. And depending on how you do your reservations perhaps just `>` on one side of that check.

Comment: FYI you can simplify it to `WHERE '2015-12-10' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`

Comment: @Barmar - so if you replicate it on sqlfiddle, it works as expected?  I have the exact same setup on my own DB and it's still giving me results outside the date range I select.  Strange...

Comment: Maybe my schema isn't the same as yours. Take a look at the fiddle and see how they differ.

Comment: @Barmar - the only difference I can find is that you are storing the hours/min/seconds, where I am just storing the month/day/year.  Rather than that, I can see no differences.

Comment: I read your condition wrong. So based on the fiddle could it be the result of an implicit cast from date to string and different culture settings?

Comment: Ok - I see one difference in Barmar's schema vs mine - my date fields are defined as 'DATE' whereas Barmar's is 'DATETIME'.  I don't see why that should make any difference though...

Comment: I also tried it with `DATE` and there was no difference. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94d37/1

Comment: I'll keep digging - at least I know the query is supposed to work.  It's probably something simple I missed on my end...always something.  Will report back if I find it.  If anyone has other suggestions would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the sub-query since it isn't necessary.  I'd also do proper JOIN while I'm at it.

```
SELECT 
    `serial`, `hostname`, `orderid`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `assigned_to`
FROM 
    `inventory`
JOIN
    `reservation` ON `serial` = `sn`
JOIN
    `orders` ON `order_id` = `orderid`
WHERE 
    `start_date` <= '2016-12-10' AND `start_date` >= '2015-12-10'
```

Comment: One change - I think you meant to put `end_date` on the second `start_date`.  But anyway, this works!  But for the life of me, I don't see why my query works in SQL Fiddle when it doesn't work in the actual DB.  Strange, but I'll go with your method.  Thanks Dave.